# Index virtual attribute Thinking Sphinx

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sphinx, thinking-sphinx

I'm wondering how one might index a virtual attribute on a model with Thinking Sphinx.  Given a Project model and some instance method which returns a boolean derived by some other information from another model, say Users, whose attribute is derived and is not on the project table in the database.

For example, suppose we have a method `is_user_eligible` such that we can query `Project.first.is_user_eligible`, and get a true or false response.  This works in the ORM already.

How can I index this virtual attribute with Thinking Sphinx?  I'm able to index virtual attributes in my django project which is on Haystack backed by Elasticsearch.  I facilitated this by having a `@property` decorator on the model method.  I figured I should be able to do this with Rails/ThinkingSphinx too, yet I get all sorts of bizarre SQL errors when trying to index.  I've tried all sorts of various constructions in setting up my index (e.g. has -vs- indexes) and all result in some sort of SQL error while indexing.

Is this possible with Thinking Sphinx?  If so, how can I index a virtual attribute?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've made it clear that the value is not available as a column on the `projects` table, but is it on an associated model instead? If so, then you could refer to it via the association:

```
has user.is_eligible, :as => :is_user_eligible
```

However, if it's not a column, but *can* be determined within the context of the SQL query, then you can use a SQL snippet as the attribute definition (I know my example is rather contrived, but should give you some idea):

```
has "(users.foo = 'bar' || users.baz = 'qux')",
  :as   => :is_user_eligible,
  :type => :boolean
```

If you're referring to associations that aren't used elsewhere in the index definition, you can force the references, or provide a SQL join statement:

```
join users
# or through more than one association:
join users.addresses
# or via your own custom join:
join "INNER JOIN users ON users.project_id = projects.id"
```

**But** if you cannot determine this value via SQL at all, then the only way to do this with Thinking Sphinx is use [real-time indices](http://freelancing-gods.com/2013/07/22/rewriting-thinking-sphinx-introducing-realtime-indices.html) *instead of* SQL-backed indices. What this then means is that instead of referring to associations and columns in your index definitions, you refer to methods instead. So, your attribute would become:

```
has is_user_eligible, :type => :boolean
```

The type *must* be specified - SQL indices can guess attribute types due to column types, but real-time indices don't have that reference point.

I realise the link to the real-time indices feature is a blog post I wrote over two years ago. However, the feature certainly works - I and others have been using it in production for quite some time (including with Flying Sphinx).

On the topic of `has` vs `indexes`: if you want to use the value as a filter or for sorting, then it must be an attribute, and thus you should use the `has` method. However, if it's textual data that you expect search queries to match on, then it should be a field, and thus use the `indexes` method.

Certainly I'd recommend switching to real-time indices anyway: it removes the need for deltas and you get up-to-date Sphinx records without needing to run 'ts:index' regularly (or at all - use `ts:generate` should your data end up in an out-of-date state). But make sure you switch *all* index definitions to real-time, instead of having some real-time and others SQL-backed.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense, I'll look into switching to real-time indices, thanks!

Comment: would it make sense to add a section on `real_time` indexing to the docs http://freelancing-gods.com/thinking-sphinx/indexing.html? Its the first google result for TS docs.

Comment: Yes, it really would! I'll try to get to that soon.